# Android file chooser not giving proper uri

Tags: android, filechooser

I am trying to upload selected file. but when I select the file from recent file section I am getting different path like

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000007352
```

this.

I want path as below:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/template.xlsx
```

but I always want exact path where file is stored. I get proper path if I go in folders and select that file but I want to select file from recent section

Comment: You did not mention that other path. So how would we know what is different?

Comment: You got an exact content scheme and it is unclear why that would not suit you. You did not tell. You got all you need to upload the selected file: a nice content scheme uri.

Answer (score 1):

I tired few ways to get real path but I failed.
so I tried different approach:

1. after getting uri, I checked if file has extension.

   ```
   val file = File(uri.getPath())
   if(file?.extension == ""){
     //file has no extension      
   }
   ```
2. If file has no extension, then get file name as below

   ```
   val returnCursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
   if (returnCursor != null) {
       val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
       returnCursor.moveToFirst()
       filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
       returnCursor.close()
   }
   ```
3. then save file temporarily in internal file storage using uri and display name

   ```
   val inputStream = AppApplicationClass.context.contentResolver.openInputStream(data)
   val header = inputStream!!.getBytes()
   val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
   fos.write(header)
   fos.close()
   ```
4. after sending temporarily saved file to api, delete temp file

   ```
   fun deleteFile(file: File) {
       if (file.exists()) {
           if (file.delete()) {
               printInDebug("file Deleted :" + file.path);
           } else {
               printInDebug("file not Deleted :" + file.path);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

p.s. this is an alternative way I found and it worked perfect for my situation, although your welcome to give answer to the question.